# Make bike suspension softer

Tags: mountain-bike, suspension

I got a mountain bike with suspension. I'm a pretty light rider so when I actually got on the bike there was no sag what so ever. I believe that it's a spring suspension and it comes with preload.

Is there anything I can do to make the suspension softer since I plan to go head out on some trails. I have already consulted my bike's manual which didn't specify anything and simply stated that I should look up my suspension manufacturers manual. Thing is the suspension is made by the same company and I can't find it anywhere online. Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some pictures of your bike, or at least give us a brand and model name?  Suspension designs vary quite a bit.

Comment: Will depend if its a coil spring or air spring. If air, you need a shock pump to set pressure. If coil, you need to buy new springs.  Many cheaper models are coil and do not come with options for springs. For others, the shops don't stock springs and presume every rider suits the 80kg it shipped with.

Comment: @mattnz - Some coil spring models are adjustable.  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41cGbkzYx9L._SX425_.jpg

Comment: As a light rider myself, and having experienced exactly what you mean, I can only suggest sticking to air suspension in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Given the limited info in your question, this answer has great limitations as well.
Preload adjustment is simply a mechanism that adjusts pressure on the spring coils. Increasing preload puts pressure on the spring, slightly reduces the distance between the coils, and results in a firmer/stiffer suspension.  The spring, under increased tension, requires more initial force to respond.  Increasing preload, reduces the amount of sag.

Much of the opposite happens when preload is reduced. The mechanical mechanism that puts pressure on the spring is physically raised away from the spring (everything is still in physical contact), the spring's coils relax a bit, and the suspension becomes more plush: less force is required to move the suspension.  Sag increases.

You state a desire to soften the suspension and reducing preload will accomplish this to some degree.  Try reducing the preload--probably all the way in your case as a light rider.  However, as alluded to in the comments, a lighter (or heavier) than average rider may need a different spring (less stiff in your case being a lighter rider).  In other words, you'll replace the current spring with a different one.   What I think in your case is that since you couldn't find any info online and the spring suspension fork carries the same branding as the bike, it's likely to be cheaply made, difficult to find parts--especially one offering choices of springs of various weights---and essentially not worth further time and cost to change out.